# How to target specific td in a HTML document with java

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to target specific td inside a tr.

This is my code:

```
        private void fletch(String name) throws IOException, JSONException {
            final String iron = "img=2";
            final String ui = "img=3";
            final String hc = "img=10";
            String url = "services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=";

            if ( name.toLowerCase().indexOf(iron.toLowerCase()) != -1 ) {
                url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool_ironman/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=";
            }else if( name.toLowerCase().indexOf(ui.toLowerCase()) != -1 ){
                url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool_ultimate/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=";
            }else if( name.toLowerCase().indexOf(hc.toLowerCase()) != -1 ){
                url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool_hardcore_ironman/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=";
            }

            String[] parts = name.split(">");
            String part2 = parts[1];
            String fin = part2.replaceAll("\\s","+");
            url+=fin;

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data("query", "Java")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(3000)
                    .post();

    //core part
            Element table1 =  doc.select("table").first();
                String body = table1.toString();
                Document docb = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body);
                Element bbd = docb.body();
                String hhk = bbd.toString();    

//This is where i dont know how to target the td data.. Tried this (cant check code so came on here):
    String overall = bbd.getElementsByTag("td").get(4).text();
```

Now this gives me this HTML code:

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border=0 style="max-width: 355px;">
<tr><td colspan="5" align="center"><b>Personal scores for big kurwaaa</b></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;padding-left:24px;"><b>Skill</b></td><td align="right"><b>Rank</b></td><td align="right"><b>Level</b></td><td align="right"><b>XP</b></td>
</tr>
<tr><td width="35"></td><td width="100"></td><td width="75"></td><td width="40"></td><td width="75"></td></tr>
<tr>

<td></td>
<td align="left"><a href="overall.ws?table=0&user=big+kurwaaa">
Overall
</a></td>
<td align="right">7,430</td>
<td align="right">466</td>
<td align="right">6,164,312</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><img class="miniimg" src="http://www.runescape.com/img/rsp777/hiscores/skill_icon_attack1.gif"></td>
<td align="left"><a href="overall.ws?table=1&user=big+kurwaaa">
Attack
</a></td>
<td align="right">14,475</td>
<td align="right">19</td>
<td align="right">4,304</td>

</tr>
```

I want to target the 3 td with data inside every tr. So for example:

```
<td align="right">7,430</td>
<td align="right">466</td>
<td align="right">6,164,312</td>
```

and so on from the "overall" tr to the last. Is there any way to do in a simple way that will give me the option to loop through the data and create a JSON/map?

Ps: new to java

Comment: Do you want 3rd td for every tr ? or From 3rd td to last td of every tr ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam from 3rd to last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the tr tags inside bbd use getElementsByTag.
It will return Elements, by which you can browse through all the tr tags by index (0 based index).If want to skip first 3 tr tags just start loop from index : 3, and so for td tags
Here is the demo code :

```
Elements trList = bbd.getElementsByTag("tr");

for (int i = 3; i < trList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("----------------- TR START -----------------");
    Elements tdList = trList.get(i).getElementsByTag("td");
    for (int j = 2; j < tdList.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(tdList.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println("------------------ TR END ------------------");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer. Cant upvote because of reputation, but thank you so much. Ps. changed the System.out.println(tdList.get(j)); to System.out.println(tdList.get(j).text()); to get the values. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

```
        String url = "yourUrl";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element table = doc.select("table[class=tableClass]").first();
        Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td[align=right]").iterator();
        iterator.next();//skip first
        iterator.next();//skip second
        System.out.println(iterator.next().text());
```

Comment: Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td[align=right]").iterator(); throws nullpointerex

Comment: @CollapsRanger2 I can see very well that td align=right exists so propably NPE comes from table, so make sure that you put right name of class of it